# Grails\Groovy Syntax Sugar not being added in Webflow integration tests on command line

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-controller, spring-tool-suite, syntactic-sugar

I have an integration test that tests a webflow, whenever it reachs a certain point in the controller code being tested I see an error similar to:

```
org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing org.codehaus.groovy.grails.webflow.engine.builder.ClosureInvokingAction@ac0e86f in state 'blahQuestions' of flow 'blahBlah' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
    at grails.test.WebFlowTestCase.signalEvent(WebFlowTestCase.groovy:142)
    at com.blah1.blah2.blah3.blah4.BlahFlowIntegrationTests.testblahQuestions(BlahFlowIntegrationTests.groovy:91)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: blahMessage for class: org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap
    at com.blah1.blah2.blah3.blah4.BlahController$_closure2_closure15_closure22.doCall(BlahController.groovy:178)
```

is thrown by the offending piece: `flow.blahMessage = ''` where `flow.put('blahMessage', '')` works without errors.  This only happens when I run the tests from the command line: `grails test-app integration:`, test ran from eclipse `RightClick on test -> Run As -> Grails Command (test-app)` work fine.

Grails 2.2.3

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Update:

When I run the test via command line by itself the test will pass, but if I run all the integration tests it fails.

Comment: you wrote: `Sorry BalRog the typo was my bad on the question, in the actual code they match, I have to modify it per policy, I should have double checked all the spelling.` Actually I made a mistake too. I intended to post my "answer" as a comment. I've taken it down now.

Comment: you also wrote: `I suspect it is being treated as a fixed-property class I just don't know why since it works fine in the actual code.` It appears that `LocalAttributeMap` will not let you add new attributes (map keys) after its attribute set is initialized. Is it possible that you instantiated as `LocalAttributeMap` in one context but not the other?

Comment: As far as the two different ways of setting the value, the one line is the only difference when I run the tests, there is no other code change between test runs.  I am using `setCurrentState('blahQuestions')` instead of starting the flow from the beginning.  However the one line code changes fixes that so I don't think its related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was test pollution as evidenced by my edit 'When I run the test via command line by itself the test will pass, but if I run all the integration tests it fails'.  Turns out other integration tests where using `@TestFor` and `@Mock` in them, which you should only be using in unit tests.

I figured this out by following Ted Naleid's [article](http://naleid.com/blog/2012/05/22/fixing-grails-tests-that-pass-in-isolation-but-fail-when-run-as-a-suite) '*Fixing Grails Tests That Pass in Isolation but Fail When Run as a Suite*' **which is exactly what was happening for me**.  The article provides a groovy class which you can use to find the smallest combination of tests where your test will still fail.